# When I build a c# project where does the service reference code go

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service-reference

when I build a project/solution that has a service reference in it, where is its compiled code?

If I have a project called JR.Rowing.Utilities that has an output of class library, the \bin directory contains:

```
JR.Rowing.Utilities.dll
JR.Rowing.Utilities.dll.config
JR.Rowing.Utilities.dll.xml
JR.Rowing.Utilities.pdb
```

Is the code for the service reference contained in one of these four files?

If I have another -already built- project that depends on calling on a new version of the service reference found in this one can I just copy these dll files over the old ones of this project?

Thanks!

Comment: I've only got files in my \dll and \dll\debug folder. In my project output \bin\debug is my 'output path'. I know what you're talking about with the property of 'copy to output directory' (that is probably the same as copy to local?) but I don't see that option on either the Service Reference top level solution explorer item or anything below it when I go to properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiled code for the service reference will be in the `JR.Rowing.Utilities.dll` file. The configuration generated by adding the service reference will go into your `App.config` file which, when compiled, ends up being your `JR.Rowing.Utilities.dll.config` file.

The JR.Rowing.Utilities.pdb is your debug file which is generated because your project is being built using the Debug configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I'm currently debugging an issue which I think is related to different versions of service references

Answer (score 0):

No it is not in the files you have mentioned.

There is separate folder and separate tree view item in solution explorer for service reference.

[image]